# match and schema shortcuts appear to not be working correctly for this scenario

Tags: karate

I ran into these issues on a larger scale, in our testing, and then again when creating this smaller testable sample

```
Feature:
  Scenario:
    * configure continueOnStepFailure = true

    * def sampleResponse =
    """
    {
      account: "123456",
      name: "sampletest",
      location: {
        locationId: "MyTown",
        latitude: "",
        longitude: "",
        timeZoneId: "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
    """
    * def location1 = sampleResponse.location
    * def sampleResponse2 =
    """
    {
      location: {
        locationId: "MyTown",
        timeZoneId: "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
    """
    * def location2 = sampleResponse2.location

    * print 'location1.latitude is:__',location1.latitude
    * print 'location2.latitude is:__',location2.latitude

    * match location1.latitude == location2.latitude
    * match location2.latitude == '#null'
    * match location2.latitude == '#string'
    * match location2.latitude == '#notpresent'

    * def loc2Value = location2.latitude == '#notpresent' ? 'missing' : 'valid'
    * print 'loc2Value is:__',loc2Value
```

With the above code, there are a couple issues

1. line 31 returns the following value for latitude although the field is not present
   `14:58:32.705 [print] location2.latitude is:__ null`
2. if the value equates to null, then line 34 should pass, but it fails
3. line 36 passes although the printed value is null
4. when doing a comparison of latitude to #notpresent, in line 38, the value in line 39 is returned as `valid` although ternary values should be `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse` which appears to be contradictary to the documentation [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#conditional-logic) that states "Here we want to call a file only if a condition is satisfied:", but the karate.call is after the : rather than the ?

[image]

Comment: sorry, I pass on this as it is too complicated. stack overflow guidelines require you to not combine multiple questions into one complex example. screenshots don't help at all. I can't make out line numbers. `continueOnStepFailure` is something that would be removed in future so don't use it. please simplify: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The line numbers would be present if you copy the code into an IDE.  The numbered issues all equate to the same problem that I am experiencing, with the exception of #4 which is an issue with the documentation it appears.  Please let me know if you would like me to refine the 3 issues into a single question.

Comment: line numbners are also present in the image attached