# SchemaValidation not correct - reporting null for not present value

Tags: karate

This is a subset of the issues pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889415/match-and-schema-shortcuts-appear-to-not-be-working-correctly-for-this-scenario?noredirect=1)

I ran into these issues on a larger scale, in our testing, and then again when creating this smaller testable sample

```
Feature:
  Scenario:
    * configure continueOnStepFailure = true

    * def sampleResponse =
    """
    {
      account: "123456",
      name: "sampletest",
      location: {
        locationId: "MyTown",
        latitude: "",
        longitude: "",
        timeZoneId: "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
    """
    * def location1 = sampleResponse.location
    * def sampleResponse2 =
    """
    {
      location: {
        locationId: "MyTown",
        timeZoneId: "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
    """
    * def location2 = sampleResponse2.location

    * print 'location1.latitude is:__',location1.latitude
    * print 'location2.latitude is:__',location2.latitude

    * match location1.latitude == location2.latitude
    * match location2.latitude == '#null'
    * match location2.latitude == '#string'
    * match location2.latitude == '#notpresent'

    * def loc2Value = location2.latitude == '#notpresent' ? 'missing' : 'valid'
    * print 'loc2Value is:__',loc2Value
```

location2.latitude prints as null, but fails the test for '#null' however it does pass the test for '#notpresent' but not as a conditional.

[image]