# Ternary operations seem to incorrect within a conditional

Tags: karate

This is a subset of the issues pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889415/match-and-schema-shortcuts-appear-to-not-be-working-correctly-for-this-scenario?noredirect=1)

I ran into these issues on a larger scale, in our testing, and then again when creating this smaller testable sample

```
Feature:
  Scenario:
    * configure continueOnStepFailure = true

    * def sampleResponse =
    """
    {
      account: "123456",
      name: "sampletest",
      location: {
        locationId: "MyTown",
        latitude: "",
        longitude: "",
        timeZoneId: "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
    """
    * def location1 = sampleResponse.location
    * def sampleResponse2 =
    """
    {
      location: {
        locationId: "MyTown",
        timeZoneId: "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
    """
    * def location2 = sampleResponse2.location

    * print 'location1.latitude is:__',location1.latitude
    * print 'location2.latitude is:__',location2.latitude

    * match location1.latitude == location2.latitude
    * match location2.latitude == '#null'
    * match location2.latitude == '#string'
    * match location2.latitude == '#notpresent'

    * def loc2Value = location2.latitude == '#notpresent' ? 'missing' : 'valid'
    * print 'loc2Value is:__',loc2Value
```

The conditional (ternary) operator mentioned in [the documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#conditional-logic) appears to be contradictary as ternary values should be `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`.  This is shown by `* def loc2Value = location2.latitude == '#notpresent' ? 'missing' : 'valid'` resulting in a valid result although the `* match location2.latitude == '#notpresent'` passes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to make just one thing clear. The ternary operator is pure JS. The `match` and things like `#notpresent` are Karate specialities. You cannot mix the two.

I also boiled down your example into something simpler and which follows the [MCVE principles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) outlined by Stack Overflow. Questions that are hard for others to read are unlikely to get any attention.

```
* def response2 = { locationId: "MyTown", timeZoneId: "America/Chicago" }
* match response2 contains { latitude: '#notpresent' }
* def latitude = response2.latitude ? 'valid' : 'missing'
* print 'latitude is:', latitude
```

Finally I urge you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475 - In my opinon, you are not using Karate the right way, you seem to be writing "overly clever" tests. These are harder to write (as you are most certainly experiencing) and even harder to maintain by other teams. For example it took me fifteen minutes to even begin to understand what your original question was  all about, and I don't have the time to look at your other questions which suffer from the same problem.

Comment: I agree everything in a single file or simplistic approach is best, but in your above response, you did not account for the situation.  Your match for `{ latitude: '#notpresent' }` will fail when a value is present, and not proceed further hence the desire for the conditional rather than duplicating the test and writing logic to determine which account(s) are expected to have or not have the latitude value populated.  When testing 1 account for 1 scenario, the above may work, but we test 100's of accounts across 100's of scenarios where this duplication is not ideal.

Comment: As for ternary operations and karate specialities, I see occurances of this within the documentation and post that seem to sugesst this mix is allowed, such as __num in `* def expected = __num == 0 ? 'name is Bob and age is 5' : 'name is Nyan and age is 6'` (documentation) and karate.match `* def result = karate.match(foo.data, bar.data).pass ? { pass: true } : { pass: false }` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237913/2048207).  If this is not allowed, that explains the issue, but that is not very clear in the documentation.

Comment: set assertions as follows, but these are simply a workaround as the actual value of location2 should not be null `* def location2Value = location2.latitude == null ? '' : scpResponse.latitude
    * match location1.latitude == '##(location2Value)'
    * def location2Value = location2.longitude == null ? '' : location2.longitude
    * match location1.longitude == '##(location2Value)'`

Comment: @mike on documentation - you are welcome to contribute updates, it is all open source. my point is you should not even have "conditionals" in tests. but if you explain what is the kind of scenario you want to test (with a simple example) ask another question and I will try to answer it. and the other point is duplication is very much ok (I would argue even "ideal") because the most important thing is to be able to understand what your test is doing and not have to worry about "more code"

Comment: I appreciate the open source nature of karate, but this unknown, of what should and should not work, is not something that I would feel comfortable updating.  When discovered, as in this case, it appears to be more of a bug rather than how it should work, so I would not want to update documentation solely based on my findings as they could be incorrect.  I would prefer to leave the documentation of how it should or should not work, to the developers and project owners such as yourself.