# Unable to assert two json files in karate tests

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am trying to assert two json in karate. however the assertion fails.
The following is the assertion error

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: 07-SbaProbePostActions.feature:71 - path: $[1], actual: {key=172.22.0.5|46590|172.22.0.7|8080|1, packet={ip={src=172.22.0.7, dst=172.22.0.5}, tcp={src=8080, dst=46590}, http2={headers=[{"name":"3gpp-sbi-message-priority","value":"24"},{"name":":status","value":"200"},{"name":"content-length","value":"367"},{"name":"content-type","value":"application\/json"}], body={"headers":[{"key":"user-agent","value":"Vert.x-WebClient/4.4.4"},{"key":"header-1","value":"header-value-1"},{"key":"header-2","value":"header-value-2"},{"key":"x-request-id","value":"13a9784b-d218-4a18-8f60-722698dfb7e3"},{"key":"content-type","value":"application/json"},{"key":"content-length","value":"55"}],"content":{"key":"sample-key","value":"sample-value"}}}}, streamId=1}, expected: {key=172.22.0.5|46590|172.22.0.7|8080|1, packet={ip={src=172.22.0.7, dst=172.22.0.5}, tcp={src=8080, dst=#number? _ >=32768 && _ <= 60999}, http2={headers=[{"name":"3gpp-sbi-message-priority","value":"24"},{"name":":status","value":"200"},{"name":"content-length","value":"367"},{"name":"content-type","value":"application\/json"}], body={"headers":[{"key":"user-agent","value":"#regex ^Vert.x-WebClient/[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(-.*)?$"},{"key":"header-1","value":"header-value-1"},{"key":"header-2","value":"header-value-2"},{"key":"x-request-id","value":"#uuid"},{"key":"content-type","value":"application/json"},{"key":"content-length","value":"55"}],"content":{"key":"sample-key","value":"sample-value"}}}}, streamId=#number}, reason: all key-values did not match
```

The following is the command i am using in my karate file.

```
And match pcapngEventsB[1] == expectedEventsB[1]
```

The value of pcapngEventsB[1] is below

```
    {
  key=172.22.0.5|39416|172.22.0.7|8080|1,
  packet={
    ip={
      src=172.22.0.7,
      dst=172.22.0.5
    },
    tcp={
      src=8080,
      dst=39416
    },
    http2={
      headers=[
        {
          "name": "3gpp-sbi-message-priority",
          "value": "24"
        },
        {
          "name": ":status",
          "value": "200"
        },
        {
          "name": "content-length",
          "value": "367"
        },
        {
          "name": "content-type",
          "value": "application\/json"
        }
      ],
      body={
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "user-agent",
            "value": "Vert.x-WebClient/4.4.4"
          },
          {
            "key": "header-1",
            "value": "header-value-1"
          },
          {
            "key": "header-2",
            "value": "header-value-2"
          },
          {
            "key": "x-request-id",
            "value": "ffa04802-be33-43cb-a2e6-4700ef0b0511"
          },
          {
            "key": "content-type",
            "value": "application/json"
          },
          {
            "key": "content-length",
            "value": "55"
          }
        ],
        "content": {
          "key": "sample-key",
          "value": "sample-value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  streamId=1
}
```

and value of expectedEventsB[1] is below

```
{
  key=172.22.0.5|39416|172.22.0.7|8080|1,
  packet={
    ip={
      src=172.22.0.7,
      dst=172.22.0.5
    },
    tcp={
      src=8080,
      dst=#number?_>=32768&&_<=60999
    },
    http2={
      headers=[
        {
          "name": "3gpp-sbi-message-priority",
          "value": "24"
        },
        {
          "name": ":status",
          "value": "200"
        },
        {
          "name": "content-length",
          "value": "367"
        },
        {
          "name": "content-type",
          "value": "application\/json"
        }
      ],
      body={
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "user-agent",
            "value": "#regex ^Vert.x-WebClient/[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(-.*)?$"
          },
          {
            "key": "header-1",
            "value": "header-value-1"
          },
          {
            "key": "header-2",
            "value": "header-value-2"
          },
          {
            "key": "x-request-id",
            "value": "#uuid"
          },
          {
            "key": "content-type",
            "value": "application/json"
          },
          {
            "key": "content-length",
            "value": "55"
          }
        ],
        "content": {
          "key": "sample-key",
          "value": "sample-value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  streamId=#number
}
```

when i compare the json it fails with error

```
reason: all key-values did not match
```

I took a diff of the actual and expected json . the following is the diff

```
diff actual.json expected.json
10c10
<       dst=39416
---
>       dst=#number?_>=32768&&_<=60999
35c35
<             "value": "Vert.x-WebClient/4.4.4"
---
>             "value": "#regex ^Vert.x-WebClient/[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(-.*)?$"
47c47
<             "value": "ffa04802-be33-43cb-a2e6-4700ef0b0511"
---
>             "value": "#uuid"
65c65
<   streamId=1
---
>   streamId=#number
```

appreciate any help how to fix this issue. thank you

Comment: I'm going to pass on this until this question is simplified instead of dumping your existing json. a 2 or 3 line json should suffice to explain the issue, see this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77904247/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas I have added one line of assertion error .

Comment: sorry I don't have time to read all your json, the second example is not even valid JSON